# VB.Net How do I read/write custom config file

Tags: vb.net, configuration-files

**Environment: .Net 3.5 VB.net (C#ok too)**

I wrote a multi-project WinForms app that needs to load a couple dozen variables from a client section of a config file based on user's selection of client. Also some program variables need to be loaded as well. So far so good, I put them in an `app.config` file.

In the `appSettings` section I put the main program variables. e.g.

```
<appSettings> 
    <add key="LocalServerName" value="PHILDESKTOP" />
```

and I created a `ClientParameters` section for the selectable ones. E.g.

```
<ClientParameters>  
    <Cust1>  
        <setting name="ClientName"   serializeAs="String">  
            <value>Customer Name 1</value>  
        </setting>
```

**Here's my problem:**

- I deployed using Click Once and the `app.exe.config` file is hard to find to make changes
- I discovered that the `app.config` file is not writeable for a good reason.. it is loaded into memory during program start-up.
- I find I need an admin to be able to add/update the client section parameters after deployment. I want to program that ability with a `ListView` or something.
- I think I have written poor code that must iterate to find a setting see below

  ```
    Dim sectionName As String
    sectionName = "ClientParameters/" + ClientCode
    Dim section As System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection = _
       DirectCast(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.GetSection(sectionName),  _
       System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection)
    For Each setting As System.Configuration.SettingElement In section.Settings
        Dim value As String = setting.Value.ValueXml.InnerText
        Dim name As String = setting.Name
        If name.ToLower = SettingName.ToLower Then
            Return value
        End If
    Next
  ```

So what I want to do is to split off the client section of the `app.config` and make something like `client.config`.

**I need some good example XML read/write code to:**

- load the client.config file
- select a particular client section
- load my client variables from the values in that section

Anyone got some good links or advice?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? Seems obvious one would want a read/write config file with an app if there is no DB attached.

Answer (score 5):

Can you just use the built-in settings? [Here's a tutorial](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/72654-using-settings/). Any settings scoped as User can be edited using the `My.Settings` "namespace". No reading/writing XML and everything's strongly typed. Anything scoped as Application are basically read-only values.

```
    'Set value
    My.Settings.FirstName = "Chris"

    'Load value
    Dim F = My.Settings.FirstName

    'Persist values
    My.Settings.Save()
```

Comment: Yeah, I might reconsider that. User variables are indeed read/write. Might be the simplest way to manage. Thinking it over.. maybe my mindset is stuck in the old .ini paradigm.

Comment: well thanks @Chris Haas, that is goo tutorial for User scope. BUt how about if it's Application scope? How do we change its value without we re-run the app? my dataset (database) is stored in Application scope using its connection string... sigh. :(

Answer (score 2):

This is an XY question.  You are asking for a solution for Y while the *real* problem is X.  AppSettings are supposed to be *easy* to read.  When you find yourself in a situation where it is suddenly no longer easy to read then an AppSetting is useless to you.

Not so sure what a better solution might be, no great hints in your question.  Sounds to me that ClickOnce is what's getting you in trouble.  The W problem.

Comment: Fair enough.. good thoughts. I think it is ClickOnce that makes it hard.  Still, I want to have a separate custom.config file that I can read/write. I used a .ini file before, it was simpler.

Answer (score 0):

Noticed that the link was broken in @Chris Haas' answer. But I didn't have enough reputation to comment on his post (rip) so I'll add this answer to help anyone who might need this later.

Here is the [Microsoft tutorial - Accessing application settings (Visual Basic)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/developing-apps/programming/app-settings/). This should provide a better overview on application settings and how to access and use them.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35653007)

Answer (score -1):

I wrote a blog post about reading custom configuration sections that allows you to pretty much write a comprehensive custom app.config section and access it from your code.  The process is not what I might call intuitive but I covered it in a fair amount of detail.  Once you've got the class model set up for reading the custom section, it's a cinch to reference the properties though.

http://www.endswithsaurus.com/search/label/app.config

Comment: Apologies, this has been fixed

Comment: Link broken, please do not post links.